# How to drop/delete dataframes from a dictionary based on the number of unique values in a column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dictionary of 12 `dfs` named `f` and each `df` have the same columns: `BacksGas_Flow_sccm, ContextID, StepID,Time_Elapsed, iso_forest, alarm`.

What I am trying to do is to count the number of unique values in the `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` column and if the number id unique value is less than 10, I want to delete that `df` from the dictionary.

I tried doing something like this:

```
v = list(f.values())

for i in range (0, len(v)):
    if (v[i]['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].nunique()) < 10:
        del (v[i])
```

but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-8-580f2e039fa5>", line 2, in <module>
    if (v[i]['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].nunique()) < 10:

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any suggestions as to how can I do this?

**P.S:**

The number of unique values in the `BacksGas_Flow_sccm` of all the `dfs`

```
df    unique values
1          2
2          5
3         373
4          2
5          4
6          3
7          4
8         560
9         141
10         4
11         5
12         4
```

I want to drop all the `dfs` in the dictionary except the 3rd, 8th and 9th.

I know it is not a good thing to share screenshots of the `dfs`, but since there are multiple `dfs`, it is difficult to post a sample `df` here. but this is how my dictionary of `dfs` look

[image]

Comment: I think that after deleting an item in the loop, the index resets and that's why you might be getting the error, why not do it in two steps, first retrieving the indexes of the DFs that should be deleted and next deleting those index from the lists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating Just create a new dictionary with the comprehension, keeping only the elements you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celius Stingher is right about the reason for the error

> I think that after deleting an item in the loop, the index resets and
>   that's why you might be getting the error [....]

This should work.

```
dictNew = dict()
for key,value in f.items():
    if (value['BacksGas_Flow_sccm'].nunique()>=10):
        dictNew[key] = value
f = dictNew
```

Comment: Upvoting - My preciouussssss pointssss thanks for getting the answer done! :D